# Filepath error when specifying output location for write_dta

Tags: r

I would like to programmatically specify the location of my exports when using `write.dta`. I have my working directory set to a parent folder and my script is in a child folder called "Script". I want the export to be in a child folder called "Data".

```
setwd("~/Dropbox/Files")
file_output <- "survey"
path_out <- "./Data"
write_dta(df, paste0(file_output,".dta"), path = path_out, version = 12)
```

However, I keep getting an error message when R is trying to write. It says it's trying to write to the "Script" folder (where my script file is located in) rather than the desired "Data" folder.

> Error: Failed to open '/Users/VancityPlanner/Dropbox/Files/Scripts' for writing

If I put the full path, I still get the same error message, whether it's a child folder or the parent folder (working directory) itself, so I don't think write permissions are an issue.

If I try not specifying the filepath, I have no error messages but it saves it to my working directory, which is not where I want it.

```
write_dta(df, paste0(file_output,".dta"), version = 12)
```

Comment: what happens if you put the full path in the `path=` argument ?

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue at that path. Whatever user running R should have write privileges.

Comment: @Mike I have updated my post. Specifying the full path (regardless of whether it's a child folder or the parent folder/working directory) fails with the same error message. However, if I do not specify a path at all, it saves to my working directory with no issues but that is not where I want i saved.

Comment: what OS are you using? can you show the full wd?

Comment: @Mike macOS 10.15.7 The full wd is "/Users/VancityPlanner/Dropbox/Files/" I have no issues when using `write.csv`

Comment: oh I think you just have to combine your path_out and file_output into one string and feed that to the file= argument

Comment: @Mike I tried using `write_dta(df, paste0(path_out, file_output,".dta"), version = 12)` where I combine path_out and file_output, but it simply writes to the working directory and includes the path_out in the filename. How should I format the code differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I show where my working directory is pointing and then I change the path of where I want to save the document in the path statement. Note it has the file path `G:/` and the dataset name appended all together. I have a PC but no reason why this shouldn't work on a mac.

```
library(haven)

getwd()  
#"C:/Users/myname/Documents"
write_dta(data = mtcars, path = "G:/mtcars.dta", version = 12)
```